# Windows 7 - different types of WiFi signal strength icons

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

[image: Normal]

[image: Different]

Any idea whats the difference between the 2 types of signal icons?

Usually I get the style on the top, but sometimes I see the one on the bottom. Have no clue what triggers one type instead of another

Comment: It's hard to tell from your images. Could the bottom one represent a peak connection strength that has fallen back down?

Comment: @BradPatton I'll keep an eye on the pattern. But, 2,4,5 bars of signal shows the normal icon. 3 bars shows this one. (Was hoping this is in some document somewhere!)

Answer (score 0):

Disable your alternate wireless connections which are not active under the adapter settings. (i.e. bluetooth or other wireless connections which you are not using). I am not sure what the grey is supposed to indicate, but this alleviated the problem for me.